# Individual check boxes will not be shown on “ Newsletter” View Style , for my document library and for the Announcement list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2013, view-styles

I have the following list:-
1.  Document library
2.  Announcement list.

I did the following changes for the “All Item” view:-

1. I change the View style from “Default” to “Newsletter”.
2. Under Tabular View I kept the “Allow individual item checkboxes” checked.

But when I browse to the All items view I cannot see any check boxes, as follow (i include the settings i did, and how the document library is shown without checkboxes):-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a limitation on the view style, I've replicated the settings in 2010 and checkboxes do not appear as well.

Comment: then how come, they kept the option to select individual items , while it does not work on the Newsletter view !!

Comment: is there any work around ?

Comment: Not that I know of off hand, possibly modifying one of the XSL templates, but I've never looked at this particular issue specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the Selection Check boxes only relate to the Default Style. (Sadly I think this is by design)